# calling an object twice overrides previous returned data even when objects are stored in array

Tags: php

I am storing multiple objects into a config array.

for example like this

```
class Test
{
    private $config = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->abc();
        $this->def();
    }

    public function abc()
    {
        $this->config['abc'] = new someClass('abc');
    }

    public function def()
    {
        $this->config['def'] = new someClass('def');
    }

    public function printTest()
    {
        return $this->config;
    }
}

class someClass
{
    public function __construct($value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

my problem that i do see the object data when I print_r the config variable. What I cannot understand is why I cannot echo out the value of the first object `abc` after i try storing the second object `def` into the config array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to print config['def'] you need to express that that is the data you want.  Now that

```
$this->config
```

is

```
array('abc'=>'abc', 'def'=>'def')
```

you just say

```
return $this->config['def'];
```

Personally, I feel like a function named printSomething() should print the data to the screen (or atleast return a string, so I'd say

```
function printConfig()
{
    $tmp = "";
    foreach($this->config as $key=>$value)
    {
        $tmp .= "Config option:{$key} value is {$value}<br>";
    }
    return $tmp;
}
```

Comment: please explain, i'm curious now. Should I call the setters in a `__call()` function?

Comment: I misunderstood the question.  new answer is passed update.  Also, just as I am saying return $this->config['def'] I could say $this->config['abc']